# Why does my output keep showing "No repeated digits"?

Tags: arrays, c, loops

I cannot seem to find my error .

If I were to key in 28212 or just any number that contain multiple digits , it would give me the output "No repeated digits".

```
// Check numbers for repeated digits
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main (void)
{
    bool digit_seen[10] = {false} ;
    int digit ;
    long n;


    printf("Enter a number: ");
    scanf("%1d", &n);
    while(n > 0){
        digit = n % 10 ;
        if (digit_seen[digit])
            break;

        digit_seen[digit] = true;
        n /= 10;
    }
    if (n > 0)
        printf("Repeated digits\n");
    else
        printf("No repeated digits\n");
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Typo: `%1d` should be `%ld`

Comment: `%1d` means to read just 1 digit into `n`. So you're setting `n = 2`, which doesn't have any repeating digits. Also, `%d` is for `int`, not `long`.

Comment: If you enable verbose warnings, the compiler should have warned that you had the wrong formatting code for `long`.

Comment: Once you fix the `scanf()` mistake, you need to fix the final condition. As it is, at the end of the loop `n` will always be zero (after repeated division by ten): you need to check every element of `digit_seen` until you find a `true` one or reach the end ... or maybe rethink yor approach :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have used `%1d` which is only reading one character from the integer input. Since the input has only one character it is always printing `No repeated digits`

Since n is `long`, you should use `%ld`.